# How can i get tags names mapped to user - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
Users    Tags      usertags

id       id        userid
name     name      tagid
```

I  need to retrieve the tags associated to the group of users with the search tag.

In Simple . Same tagged example we have here in stackoverflow.

Here we have questions instead of users.

Hope my question is clear.

I need mysql query with joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tags
LEFT JOIN usertags
ON tags.id = usertags.tagid
LEFT JOIN users
ON usertags.userid=users.id
WHERE tags.name='something'
```

Comment: if i have multiple tags ..i need to get all the tags assigned to the user who have all the multiple tags>.....